# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS FN+buttons causes the laptop to shut down

Tags: 22.04, lenovo

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Lenovo Legion Slim 5 modificate "screen brightness control"(<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>) causes the laptop to shut down every time. Other controlling buttons periodically as well (turning on/off the touchpad and others).

There is an issue on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2124355#p2124355, but maybe someone knows a solution?